# Determining date packages were added/removed by apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I recently logged onto a server, and noticed the git package is no longer installed.  Would like to investigate, is there a way via apt-get or dpkg to list the date packages were added or removed, or a good log to checkout (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/log/dpkg.log` is just what the doctor ordered. :)

Comment: Thanks EEAA.  It only seems to shows info from the last time apt-get installed something though?  The uninstall probably happened a while back.

Comment: If you have logrotate running, check the `/var/log/dpkg.log.X.gz` files.

Comment: I don't.  Bummer